# DatePicker Component no longer available in material-ui v1.0.0-alpha.22

Tags: material-ui

I just want to know if the DatePicker Component will be removed from the material-ui?
I'm trying this version `v1.0.0-alpha.22` of material-ui and the component is no longer available

This is how I'm importing it `import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';`

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the same thing.  It actually is now located in the TextField component as

type = 'date'

Comment: Oh I see. But thats the browser default date type which I think its only supported on Chrome